# c# get feasible values using in a string, then search in lookup, then limit search by a string

Tags: c#

Having a lookup structure like

```
public class LookupEntry
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

//inside main
var list = new List<LookupEntry>(new LookupEntry[] 
{
    new LookupEntry() {Key="A", Value="mo" }, 
    new LookupEntry() {Key="A", Value="nu"},
    new LookupEntry() {Key="B", Value="ag"},
    new LookupEntry() {Key="B", Value="bi"},
    new LookupEntry() {Key="B", Value="cu"},
    new LookupEntry() {Key="C", Value="tu"},
    new LookupEntry() {Key="D", Value="uo"},
    new LookupEntry() {Key="D", Value="vu"},
    new LookupEntry() {Key="D", Value="zu"},
    new LookupEntry() {Key="E", Value="ve"}
});
string original = "AD";
string large = "mobivecuvumonubinuzumozu";
//               ABEBDAABADAD would be codified string
```

And using original string "AD" I would like to get possible codified strings
so for instance I would get (using lookup)

```
    "mouo"
    "nuuo"
    "movu"
    "nuvu"
    "mozu"
    "nuzu"
```

for AD string

But instead Of getting all combinations from lookup I would like To limit search with large string getting possible combinations
            so in that case I would get 
                "nuzu"
                "mozu"

I am doing something like

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
var allAs = lookup["A"].ToList();
var allDs = lookup["D"].ToList();
```

But I do not know how to continue, is it a good option to search all possibilities fisrt and then remove the ones that are not in string

Comment: .ok i saw you edited,now,what you want to limit the string?...the amount of results say,if there are 10 results you want to limit by some number or a predefined number?...and since there could be like in your example 5 results and you need limiting to for example 2 which 2 to bring-first 2 ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following idea:

```
var query = allAs.SelectMany(x => allDs, (x, y) => x + y).Where(large.Contains);
```

This does a cartesian join on the two lists, and filters by whether the result is in the large string.

Alternatively, in LINQ query syntax, it looks like this:

```
var query = from x in allAs
            from y in allDs
            where large.Contains(x + y)
            select x + y;
```

Output:

> mozu
>
> nuzu